# C++ Struct : Function definition does not declare parameters

Tags: c++, struct

I created 2 Structures tnode and node.

```
struct tnode
{
    int data;
    struct tnode *left;
    struct tnode *right;
};

struct node
{
    struct tnode *treenode:
    struct node *next;
};

struct node* InsertNode(struct node *head, struct tnode *_treenode)
```

I got these errors:

```
[Error] function definition does not declare parameters

In function 'node* InsertNode(node*, tnode*)':

[Error] 'struct node' has no member named 'treenode'

[Error] 'struct node' has no member named 'next'
```

Comment: Hi krish welcome to stackoverflow. you should only need to use the `struct` key word when  defining the struct itself and when doing forward declarations. In this case you should only need to use the struct keyword for `struct tnode{...};` and `struct node{...};`

Comment: You added C and C++ tag. Which language do you use?

Comment: Are these the exact error message for this exact code snippet?

Comment: Hi I used C++. Here is my code https://ideone.com/g9yRWh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of `struct node` has  the line `struct tnode *treenode:`. It should end with a semicolon not with a colon. If you change that, everything works fine. Sadly the compilation errors are not helpful at all to find that out.